# Works with long type, but not with any other variable type

Tags: vba, types

This is the code, that is bug-free:

```
Sub Minus()  

Dim cell As Long
cell = ActiveCell.Value
Dim offsetcell As Long
offsetcell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & cell & "-" & offsetcell

End Sub
```

As soon as I change the variable to **any other type (preferably Double)** the code stops working and bug appears in the concatenated function below.

- Any ideas why?
- i would like full original value minus adjacent cell (one left).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably casting a decimal comma to text which will break the formula. So, convert using **Str** that will return a dot as the decimal separator:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Str(cell) & "-" & Str(offsetcell)
```

That works here.

PS: Don't use native object names (cell) as the name for variables holding completely different values types.

Comment: Yes, I already solved the issue, as it was a decimal spearator problem. Even easier solution is to use .formulaLocal. Thank you for your answer!